# How can I solve initial velocity for a projectile given the max height and distance

Tags: physics, projectile-motion

[image]

I'm trying to find the initial velocity of a tennis ball (magnitude and angle) given the initial height, max height and max range.

I believe this is possible with the equations below but I'm struggling with the algebra and trig to make it work!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the time to fall from $y_{max}$ to $0$ and from $y_{max}$ to $y_0$.  This gives you the time of flight.  From $x_f$ you can get $V_0\cos \theta$

Compute the vertical speed after the fall from $y_{max}$ to $y_0$.  This is the initial upward speed $V_0 \sin \theta$

Take the $\arctan$ of the ratio of initial velocities to get $\theta$.  Use that to get $V_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. can you explain the second step some more?"Compute the vertical speed after the fall from ymax to y0. This is the initial upward speed V0sinθ"

Comment: The loss of speed when rising that much is the same as the gain in speed when falling, from conservation of energy.  I assumed you are used to computing the speed after falling a given distance, so I used that.